# Client-server what is the limitation of server's processes run time?

Tags: web-services, web, client, client-server, webclient

I have a certain program that recieves input and returnes an output with a run-time of about 2 seconds,

Now, i want to run this program online on a server that can handle multiple connections (lets say up to 100k), 
on each client-server session the program will launch,
the client will hand the server the program's input and will wait for the program to end to recieve the server's respond (program's output),

Lets say the server's host is a very powerful machine - e.g 16 cores,

Can this work or it is to much runtime for each client?
What is the maximum runtime this kind of program can have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer because it's too large to place as a comment.

Can this work? It depends. It depends because there are a lot of variables in this problem. Let's look at some of them:

- you say it takes 2 seconds to compute a result. Where and how are those seconds spent? Is this pure computation or are you accessing a database, or the file system? Is this CPU bound or I/O bound? If you run computations for the full 2 seconds then you are consuming CPU which means that you can simultaneously serve only 16 clients, one per core. Are you hitting a database? Is this on the powerful server or on some other machine? If the database is the bottleneck than move this to the powerful server and have SSD drives on it.
- can you improve processing for one client? What's more efficient, doing the processing on one core or spread it across all the cores? If you can parallelize, can you limit thread contention?
- is CPU all you need? How about memory? Any backend service you access? Are those over the network? Do you have enough bandwidth?
- related to memory, what language/platform are you using? Does it have a garbage collector? Do you generate a lot of object to compute a result? Does the GC kick in and pauses your application so it cleans up and compacts the memory? Do you allocate enough memory for the application to run?
- can you cache responses and serve them to other clients or are responses custom to each client? Can you precompute the results and then just serve them to clients or can't you predict the inputs?
- Have you tried running some performance tests and profile the application to see where hotspots might show up? Can you do something about them?
- have you any imposed performance criteria? How many clients do you want to support simultaneously? Is 2 seconds too much? Can clients live with more? How much more? How many seconds does it mean an unacceptable response time?
- do you need a big server to run this setup or smaller ones work better (i.e. scale horizontally instead of vertically)?
- etc

Nobody can answer this for you. You have to do an analysis of your application, run some tests, profile it, optimize it, then repeat until you are satisfied with the results.